# How to make Child records as owner same as Case in salesforce?

Tags: apex, sharerecord

I had **master detailed** relationship with the Case and Payment1,2 etc object. Now this relationship is changed to **lookup**. Now `OWD` for `Case`, `Payment1,2` is Private. Now User is not able to access the old cases, basically unable to see any records of Payment1,2 at all.

Now I need to identify all child object records of that Case and need to make them a owner like as Case.

Could you please confirm what do I need to do ?

- Make Child Object as Owner like Case?
- Do I need to create Child Share
  Object ?

**Here is the code**

```
Set<Id> caseOwnerUpdatesSet = new Set<Id>();
caseOwnerUpdatesSet.add('KKK'); // Here will provide the list of Ids

Map<Id, Case> newCasesMap = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id IN ('KKK')]);

Map<Id, List<Payment1__c>> paymentsiInfoMap = new Map<Id, List<Payment1__c>>();

List<Payment1__c> payment1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst = new List<Payment1__c>();

for(Payment1__c si : [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Case__c 
                                     FROM Payment1__c 
                                     WHERE Case__c IN :caseOwnerUpdatesSet]){

if(!paymentsiInfoMap.containsKey(si.Case__c))
    paymentsiInfoMap.put(si.Case__c, new List<Payment1__c>{si});
else
    paymentsiInfoMap.get(si.Case__c).add(si);

                                     }

for(Case objCase : newCasesMap.values()){
    // check Owner to be updated present
    if(caseOwnerUpdatesSet.contains(objCase.Id) && paymentsiInfoMap.containsKey(objCase.Id)){
        for(Payment1__c si : paymentsiInfoMap.get(objCase.Id)){
            si.OwnerId = objCase.OwnerId;
            payment1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst.add(si);
        }
    }
}

if(!payment1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst.isEmpty()){
    update payment1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst;
}


Map<Id, List<Payment_2__c>> si2InfoMap = new Map<Id, List<Payment_2__c>>();
List<Payment_2__c> payment2InfoToUpdateOwnerLst = new List<Payment_2__c>();

// Get all Service Info records for which owner has to be changed
for(Payment_2__c si2 : [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Case__c 
                                        FROM Payment_2__c
                                        WHERE Case__c IN :caseOwnerUpdatesSet]){
if(!si2InfoMap.containsKey(si2.Case__c))
    si2InfoMap.put(si2.Case__c, new List<Payment_2__c>{si2});
else
    si2InfoMap.get(si2.Case__c).add(si2);
                                        }

for(Case objCase : newCasesMap.values()){
    // check Owner to be updated present
    if(caseOwnerUpdatesSet.contains(objCase.Id) && si2InfoMap.containsKey(objCase.Id)){
        for(Payment_2__c si2 : si2InfoMap.get(objCase.Id)){
            si2.OwnerId = objCase.OwnerId;
            payment2InfoToUpdateOwnerLst.add(si2);
        }
    }
}

if(!payment2InfoToUpdateOwnerLst.isEmpty()){
    update payment2InfoToUpdateOwnerLst;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to:

- propagate any owner change from `Case` to the child objects using e.g. a trigger
- add sharing rules for the child objects

If the child objects make no sense without the `Case` object, you should also create your own "cascading delete" i.e. when the `Case` is deleted also delete the child objects.